# How to enable saml 2.0 sso in asp.net website

Tags: c#, asp.net, single-sign-on, saml, saml-2.0

We have a website and one of our client want to use saml to authenticate their users and they have an identity provider.

Can someone direct me where to start and what are the things required to intigrate saml in our website.

Answer (score 6):

[`Kentor.AuthServices`](https://github.com/KentorIT/authservices) is an open source service provider for .NET that is designed to be as simple as possible to use in ASP.NET applications.

There are three nuget packages available

- [`Kentor.AuthServices`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Kentor.AuthServices/) core library and an Http Module for web forms applications.
- [`Kentor.AuthServices.Mvc`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Kentor.AuthServices.Mvc/) MVC controller for simple setup for MVC applications.
- [`Kentor.AuthServices.Owin`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Kentor.AuthServices.Owin/) Owin middleware for modern MVC applications and integration with ASP.NET Identity.

*Disclaimer: I'm the author of Kentor.AuthServices, but as it's free, I make no money from people using it.*

Comment: Anders, perhaps a crazy question, but can you think of any reason why after adding the Kentor Saml middleware, our app is attempting to connect to 209.61.153.179, a reverse lookup reveals it to be http://www.pierpoint-martin.com ?

Answer (score 2):

With ASP.NET, you would normally use WIF but WIF doesn't support the SAML protocol.

Two ways of doing this.

Use ADFS as a bridge so:

App. --> WIF --> ADFS --> SAML --> IDP

Use a .NET 3rd party stack in your app.

Refer: [SAML : SAML connectivity / toolkit](http://nzpcmad.blogspot.co.nz/2013/06/saml-saml-connectivity-toolkit.html)

Comment: Thanks for the response.I tried onelogin but its didnt suite our scenario.Our client already has an identity provider.So i want to know what are the things i should ask them to configure our service provider.